# How to create a simple inline calculator page?

Tags: inline-visualforce, excel

Is it possible to have an on-the-fly calculation on a Visual Force page? An APP?

I need to give our sales team an option, where they can do some simple/complicated calculations.

An example would be that once a number is entered, 3 results will appear (say in a table) that automatically represent some calculations based on the number (and the relying formula)

Is it possible to get something similar in visual page?

The result can lie either on a tabbed page, or a pop up window. Not on the Left side bar.

APP maybe?

Comment: have you tried anything like javascript to calculate ?

Comment: Short answer is yes, it's possible. But have you tried JS as Ratan asked? Would you prefer JS? Should this sit in the SF Sidebar? What have you got so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

code:

public class TestCalculator {

```
public Decimal inputField1{get;set;}
public Decimal outputField1{get;set;}
public Decimal outputField2{get;set;}
public Decimal outputField3{get;set;}

public void calculate(){
    System.debug('Entered method '+ this.inputField1);
    if(null != this.inputField1){
        this.outputField1 = 0.50 * this.inputField1;
        this.outputField2 = 0.33 * this.inputField1;
        this.outputField3 = 0.25 * this.inputField1;
    }
}
```

}

```
<apex:page controller="TestCalculator" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<apex:form id="form1">
    <apex:outputLabel ><b>Input Value</b></apex:outputLabel><br/>
    <apex:inputText id="inputField1" value="{!inputField1}" onChange="scriptCalculator()" style="background: yellow;"/><br/>
        <apex:outputPanel id="outputSection" rendered="true">
            <table border="1px">
                <tr><th>1/2 of Input</th><th>1/3 of Input</th><th>1/4 of Input</th></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><apex:inputText id="outputField1"  value="{!outputField1}" style="background: greenyellow;"/></td>
                    <td><apex:inputText id="outputField2" value="{!outputField2}" style="background: greenyellow;"/></td>
                    <td><apex:inputText id="outputField3" value="{!outputField3}" style="background: greenyellow;"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:actionFunction name="actionCalculate" action="{!calculate}" reRender="outputSection"/>
</apex:form>
<Script>
    function scriptCalculator(){
        var inputField1 = document.getElementById('{!$Component.form1.inputField1}').value;
         document.getElementById('{!$Component.form1.outputField1}').value = inputField1 * 0.5;
         document.getElementById('{!$Component.form1.outputField2}').value = inputField1 * 0.333;
         document.getElementById('{!$Component.form1.outputField3}').value = inputField1 * 0.25;    
    }
</script></apex:page>
```

you Can use either scriptCalculator() or actionCalculate() based on your wish to display the calculation logic.

You can use the same method with inline edit page.